# How to show form in a pop up of a marker using angularjs-openlayers-directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I am using [angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) , and I want to show a form and get inputs from the form.

I tried changing the label message to form template, but instead of form only a small pop up is being shown which contains nothing.

```
   label: {
                        message: '<input type="number" />'
}
```

Comment: You should be able to add content to the marker by just adding it between the tags since everything is transcluded:
https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/blob/5a30fcc99ca7242ecdcceb577aa1a5402dfb41b0/src/directives/marker.js#L81